# Finding the longest consecutive sequence of increase in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long dataset of increasing and decreasing values and I am trying to find the length of the longest sequence of values which increase one after the other.

I know this is easily done with a helper column however I am hoping there is a formula which can do it by itself.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the array formula:

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A99<A2:A100,ROW(A1:A99)),IF(A1:A99>A2:A100,IF(A1:A99<>A2:A100,ROW(A1:A99)))))+1
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

**NOTE:**

I would always use a "helper" column for this kind of task rather than this array formula.

Comment: This is really helpful thank you. One more thing, would it be possible to add an IF statement in there somewhere for it to ignore certain values? I have another column that has some description on those values and I only want the formula to take into account certain ones. E.g. they are rated 1-3 and I want it to use ones that are 1 or 2 but not onse that are 3.